# Google Analytics - event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've got a really hopefully simple question regarding Google Analytics. I've added tracking to a site and have set up Event Tracking for a link to an external page.

In the report suite under event tracking the event name comes up as the full URL for the external page. Code is below:

`<a onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'https://www.externallink.com');return false;" href="https://www.externallink.com"><img     style="padding-top:2px;" src="/common/images/ss_managemyaccount.gif" alt="" /></a>`

Now daft as this may sound, is the name for the Event showing up as the URL because I have called it that? I.e. after `'Outbound Links',` I have just used the URL? Could I call this whatever I wanted to? E.g. `Hello` or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you are populating the actual GA code.  recordOutboundLink() is some arbitrary wrapper function you or someone else made, which takes that information.  That's not actual GA code.  Post the recordOutboundLink() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Virtual Page View](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html#VirtualPageviews) to call the link anything you like. If you post your `recordOutboundLink()` function, I can help you with that.

Comment: thanks for this. But I just wanted to know if, if I change the name of `'https://www.externallink.com'` and keep the href the same, in my Report under, 'Event Tracking' will it show up as the name I define?